# Beamer - Fitting multiline title into a single one

Tags: beamer, titles, lengths, dimensions

I am trying to adjust a multiline title into a single line. I found the length of the text and check if it is larger than `\linewidth` or `\textwidth`. Both dimensions gave larger values than expected. After tinkering with it, I realized `250pt` is the magic value. I don't know how to find this programmatically.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\mytitle}{A very very very very very very very very very long title}
\newlength{\mytitlewidth}
\settowidth{\mytitlewidth}{\mytitle}

\ifdim\mytitlewidth > \linewidth % 250pt
  \title{\resizebox{\dimexpr\textwidth}{!}{\centering{\mytitle}}}
\else
  \title{\mytitle}
\fi

\author{\the\mytitlewidth, \the\linewidth}
\institute{}
\date{January 31st, 2023}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673425/beamer-have-text-box-automatically-shrink-text-size-in-sty-file

Comment: Please also note that the syntax `\centering{...}` does not make much sense. `\centering` is a switch and does not take an argument.